# What is the best way to logging out user when application uninstalled?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing application with unity and I have api for login and logout users to their profile.

Imaging user logged in application and He/She uninstall application. Then another user install the app and when run it, He/She is Logged in !

What is the best way to logging out user when application uninstalled?

Comment: ? ... in what kind of environment is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an external file to save a unique code for your user. After each run, check the file's value with the user's code on server's side data. if it matches, let him logs in.
After Uninstalling, remove this file. Then the game cannot find the user's code and will ask him to log in.